# Show Gui over Fullscreen

Tags: autohotkey

I have made a GUI:

```
Gui +AlwaysOnTop
```

I not only want it to be alwaysontop, but also always showing over fullscreen applications. In this case it works for Chrome Fullscreen, but if I try the same with Edge it doesn't appear anymore. How can I change this?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a problem with AutoHotkey, but with Edge. You can read more about it from this post on Microsoft forums:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/microsoft-edge-window-is-always-on-top-of-other/b17bbee3-21e7-48ff-a41b-5d60c127c1bc